# How to zip up a Java eclipse project so it can be easily unfolded onto another computer?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am applying for a job which is requesting that I send in some Java source code zipped up so that it can be "easily unfolded into Eclipse". So, I simply zipped up my src and test directories but if you copy and paste this into eclipse the test directory is not recognized as a source folder. Is there a better way to do this that I am missing?

Thankyou

Comment: What version of Eclipse do you have?

Comment: I usually zip up a project folder under current Eclipse workspace since it stores `.settings` folder, `.project` and `.classpath` file. It will be nicer it you can create a Ant task (build.xml) for it

Comment: Ok thanks! I will try to setup a build.xml for the project

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In Eclipse:

1. File > Export
2. Select the General > Archive File export wizard.
3. Select the project(s) to be exported.
4. Choose the archive file type (ZIP or TAR), and other options.
5. Enter the archive file name
6. Click Finish.

This gives you an archive file containing the project complete with the Eclipse project metadata, settings, etc.  (You can deselect any bits you don't want at this stage, or when you Import the project into the target Eclipse workspace.)

Answer (score 1):

If you're not worried about any project-specific configuration settings that are stored in the `.classpath` and `.project` files you can just zip archive the src directory. When you're at your new computer just extract the archive into a new folder. Then in Eclipse when you're creating a new project uncheck "Use default location" and browse to the new folder that you extracted the src archive into.

Answer (score -2):

http://agile.csc.ncsu.edu/SEMaterials/tutorials/import_export/