# Exporting a java project (in eclipse) to another computer

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

My project contains some JLabels with images. In my project I have mentioned the path for this images. But I need to export this project to another PC. Is there any way to include these images in my project or can I make a jar file that will run fine in other computers with the images that I used?

Comment: may be duplicate of [How to zip up a Java eclipse project ...?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385894/how-to-zip-up-a-java-eclipse-project-so-it-can-be-easily-unfolded-onto-another-c)

Comment: I only know that the idea with the jar wont work - my guess is that you will have to copy all the images and do some work on the paths used in your code (I think it is better to have all the project resources in a resources folder inside the project anyway - then you could simply export (as archive or as file system or...)) - or make sure that the images exist on your other computer in the exact same path

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: export to an .jar file in eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/423938/java-export-to-an-jar-file-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

Replace all hard coded paths and put them in some properties file.Make sure the paths are relative.  And then copy entire project and paste onto new PC.

Comment: I have not got the point 'the paths are relative'. May be an example can help.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#Absolute_and_relative_paths